# C: Shared memory and forking, print statement executing several times

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that calculates the collatz conjecture for a given number using shared memory. The parent will create a child process, then the child will calculate the conjecture, and using shared memory supply it to the parent so the parent can print the value out.
If the child can't calculate the full conjecture, because it runs out of space to store it in the shared memory struct, then the parent will create a new child process to continue where the last one stopped.
I'm having an issue where the print statements in the parent process that display the childs' results from shared memory are printed multiple times.

```
/*********************************
 * Applies the Collatz conjecture
 * to the given positive integer
 * using shared memory.
 *********************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE 30

typedef struct {
    int size; // Number of values in this sequence
    short partial; // Flag
    long num[MAX_SEQUENCE];
} shared_data;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Name of the shared memory segment
    const char *name = "myMemorySeg";

    // Shared memory file descriptor
    int shm_fd;

    // A pointer to the shared memory segment
    shared_data* shared_memory;

    // Handle input validation
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s num\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    // Get number from argument
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    do {
        int pid;
        // Create a child process with shared memory space
        pid = create_child(&name, &shm_fd, &shared_memory);

        // Parent
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);

            // Print out collatz results
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < shared_memory->size; i++)
                printf("%d ", shared_memory->num[i]);

            // If this was only part of the sequence
            //     Then start the next sequence at the collatz of the last sequence value
            if (shared_memory->partial)
                n = get_collatz(shared_memory->num[MAX_SEQUENCE - 1]);
        }
        // Child
        else if (pid == 0) {
            // Generate the collatz sequence and store the result in the shared memory
            int i = 0;
            shared_memory->num[i++] = n; // Store the initial number
            while (n != 1 && i < MAX_SEQUENCE) {
                n = get_collatz(n);
                shared_memory->num[i++] = n; // Store the next number
            }
            // If we have filled the sequence array and n hasn't reached 1
            //     then this is only a partial sequence
            shared_memory->partial = (i == MAX_SEQUENCE && n != 1) ? 1 : 0;
            // What is the sequence size?
            shared_memory->size = i;

            // Kill the child process
            exit(0);
        }

        // Remove the shared memory object
        shm_unlink(name);

    } while (shared_memory->partial); // While the last sequence was partial
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

/********************************
* create_child()
*
* Opens a shared memory space
* and creates a child process
* to share that space with the
* parent.
*
* Returns the process id if
* successful, otherwise exits
* the parent process.
********************************/
int create_child(char **name, int *shm_fd, shared_data** shared_memory) {
    // Create a shared memory object
    *shm_fd = shm_open(*name, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);

    // Configure the size of the shared memory object
    ftruncate(*shm_fd, sizeof(shared_data));

    // Memory map the shared memory object
    *shared_memory = (shared_data *) mmap(0, sizeof(shared_data), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, *shm_fd, 0);

    // Create child process
    int pid;
    // Return -1 if error
    if ((pid=fork()) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create child process");
        exit(1); // Kill parent process
    }
    // Otherwise return the pid created by fork
    return pid;
}

/********************************
* get_collatz()
*
* Returns the result of running
* the input n through the
* collatz conjecture function.
********************************/
int get_collatz(int n) {
    return (!(n%2)) ? (n/2) : (3*n + 1);
}
```

This is what the console output looks like:

[image: Console output]

Interestingly, if I add a print statement with a new line to the parent process before it prints out the results of the child process from shared memory like so:

```
    do {
        int pid;
        printf("\n");
        // Create a child process with shared memory space
        pid = create_child(&name, &shm_fd, &shared_memory);

        // Parent
        if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);

            // Print out collatz results
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < shared_memory->size; i++)
                printf("%d ", shared_memory->num[i]);

            // If this was only part of the sequence
            //     Then start the next sequence at the collatz of the last sequence value
            if (shared_memory->partial)
                n = get_collatz(shared_memory->num[MAX_SEQUENCE - 1]);
        }
        // Child
```

Then the print statements will be output the correct number of times.

[image: Console output with print statement]

Another interesting fact is that this solution only works if I place the newline print statement before the create_child() call, and not if I place it after.

I don't want these to be separated by new lines, I want them to print all on one line. Any ideas what is causing these extra print statements?

Comment: try flushing stdout, otherwise it gets buffered

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>` for the `wait()` function.  It is also missing the prototypes for the sub functions.  Such prototypes are needed when the function is called before the compiler sees it

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding: `ypedef struct {
    int size; // Number of values in this sequence
    short partial; // Flag
    long num[MAX_SEQUENCE];
} shared_data;`  For flexibility (and other reasons) it is best to separate a struct definition from a typedef for that struct

Comment: OT: regarding: `int n = atoi(argv[1]);`  The function: `atoi()` does not let the program know when it fails.  Suggest using: `strtol()` instead

Comment: OT: regarding: `int pid;`  this (sortof) works, however the correct type is: `pid_t`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d ", shared_memory->num[i]);`  the field `num` is an array of `long int` values so '%d' will not properly print all values.  Suggest: `printf("%ld ", shared_memory->num[i]);`

Comment: where is the code checking to assure that `n` is <= MAX_SEQUENCE?

Comment: OT: Always check the returned value from the C library functions to assure the operation was successful (and if not successful, call `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to add appropriate flush calls or you need to change your standard output not to be buffered.

The library is trying to be efficient and not actually write to the terminal until it has a full line. So it stores partial lines in a buffer. When you `fork`, you wind up with two processes that are substantially identical, that is, they each have the same buffered data. If both of them finishes a line of output, both of them will write the buffered data.

You may still have an issue that all the various outputs are jumbled up together. The more usual way to handle this is to have only one process responsible for all output and the "worker" processes communicate their results back to the "manager" process to be printed in a sane, orderly way.

Comment: Yup, simply adding a fflush(stdout); right after the printing loop in the parent process fixed the issue.